Is it possible to set which UI to render by Layer?
I want to render a specific UI by layer setting in specific time.
Which means,
[Hierarchy]
Camera (Culling Mask : UI, UI2)
Canvas (Layer : UI, RenderMode : ScreenSpace-Camera)

UI_1 (Layer : UI)
UI_2 (Layer : UI2)

When I set Camera's Culling Mask option to only 'UI', then I want to Not Render UI_2.
Is it possible?
or It's impossible that control which ui to render in under Canvas object?
I tried culling mask, layers

Afaik Canvas is rendered to the camera regardless of layers .. but sounds like something you can simply try and see right?

Canvas is rendered to the camera regardless of layers? Maybe not. If you set Canvas's Render Mode as Screen Space - Camera and set Camera's culling mask, that camera will not render a Canvas that layer is not set in Camera's culling mask option.

@derHugo I mean, If I set Camera's Culling mask as UI layer and if I made canvas as Water layer, that canvas is not rendered.

So as you can see apparently it is based on the Canvas's layer and doesn't respect child items so for your use case you might have to have sub-Canvas with your according layers
